# Implementing Blockchain and Converting Web App to DApp

Tags: go-ethereum, blockchain, dapp-development

I have my web-application which is in Angular2 (Front end) and Rails (Back end-API), now I want to implement Blockchain to this Web application, so needs to make it DApp.

Here while making the DApp, do I need to remove all the Rails Back-end(API) and convert the business logic into the smart-contracts (Ethereum)?

This application is having more than 50 API's, so should I have to write the 50+ smart contract for each API? that means I need to remove the all Rails API code.

Do I need to require to choose the cloud storage platform like Storj, Decent for storing the data?

Please guide.

Please share any On-line material/blogs which can help me into this.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1):

By my interpretation, let me break down your problem:
Your App has a front end, a database, and a bunch of APIs.

Just to make it clear you cannot convert the entire app to a dapp. Some part of it always has to centralized.

Since you have 50 APIs i'm assuming you have a login/logout/signin/signout APIs as well. It wont take long to convert these apis to smart contract.

The real issue would be to handle requests that return users with large data (audio/video). This is where storj or IPFS would come into picture.

So you can start in this order:

1. Create a front-end.
2. Start with small apis, make a smart contracts with 5 or 6 apis like login or signup.
3. Move to bigger APIs.
4. Move store large files to ipfs and save the links in the smart contracts.

hope this helps

Comment: Thanks Kashish for the answer, it clears many questions. Is it good idea to make the partial Dapps? 

Also, for the consensus mechanism As it is simple web app, is there a need of miner? I don't see the need of miner so how to set the consensus?

Comment: Ethereum abstracts all such complexities, such as mining,consensus,execution, managing the chain. If you just want to develop a dapp. You dont need to worry about this stuff. Just make a smart contract and front end.